# Importing Module depending app in multiple apps Angular project

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm using a multiple apps Angular project with a .angular-cli.json like :

```
"apps": [
{
  "name": "app1",
  "root": "src",
  "outDir": "dist/app1",
  ...
  "main": "main.ts",
 },
{
  "name": "app2",
  "root": "src",
  "outDir": "dist/app2",
  ...
  "main": "main.ts",
 }
```

I created a module and would like to use it in one of the two apps. Is it possible to use the app value to conditionnaly import the module and personalize the component of just one of the two apps ?

something like

```
  @NgModule({
    imports: [ common modules ],
    if(app == app1) imports.add(specificModuleForApp1) ;
```

and for the view

```
  <specific-component *ngIf="{app == app1}"> </specific-component>
```